# Passing character array as parameter (C kernel code)

Tags: c, arrays, string, kernel

I'm trying to print something on screen using my print function.

I've stumbled on a small problem - when I pass the character array like this:

```
char s[] = "abc";
print(s);
```

It works fine, but when i call it like this there is no effect.

```
print("abc");
```

Here is my function declaration

```
//print function 
void print(char* message);
```

Am I missing something? printf works the same way, and you can pass the string by the second way.

EDIT:

definitions

```
void print_at(char* message, int col, int row){
    if(col >= 0 && row >= 0){
        set_cursor(get_screen_offset(col,row));
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(message[i] != 0){
        print_char(message[i++],-1,-1,WHITE_ON_BLACK);
    }
}
void print(char* message){
    print_at(message, -1,-1);
}
```

EDIT2:
objdump of kernel.o

```
void start(){
    clear_screen();
    char s[] = "abc";
    print("abc");
    print(s);
    while(1);
}
```

Disassembly of section .text:

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   83 ec 28                sub    esp,0x28
   6:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   b <_start+0xb> //clear_screen()

   b:   c7 45 f4 61 62 63 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x636261 //"bca"
  12:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x0
  19:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   1e <_start+0x1e> //print()

  1e:   8d 45 f4                lea    eax,[ebp-0xc]
  21:   89 04 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
  24:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   29 <_start+0x29> //print()

  29:   eb fe                   jmp    29 <_start+0x29>
  2b:   90                      nop
```

EDIT3:

Since this might be something with the way I am initilising the enviroment, here are the 2 files responsible:

pmode.asm -initializes segments, and jumps to start of kernel

```
[bits 16]
switch_to_pm:

    cli     ; switch interuppts off
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; load global descriptor table 

    mov eax, cr0 ; set control registers first bit to protected mode
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0, eax 

    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm ;flush cache by far jump

[bits 32]
init_pm:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    call BEGIN_PM
```

here is how I build the gdt:

; GDT

```
gdt_start: 

gdt_null: ; the mandatory null descriptor 
    dd 0x0      ; ' dd ' means define double word ( i.e. 4 bytes ) 
    dd 0x0 

gdt_code: ; the code segment descriptor 
    ; base =0 x0 , limit =0 xfffff , 
    ; 1 st flags : ( present )1 ( privilege )00 ( descriptor type )1 -> 1001 b 
    ; type flags : ( code )1 ( conforming )0 ( readable )1 ( accessed )0 -> 1010 b 
    ; 2 nd flags : ( granularity )1 (32- bit default )1 (64- bit seg )0 ( AVL )0 -> 1100 b 
    dw 0xffff       ; Limit ( bits 0-15) 
    dw 0x0          ; Base ( bits 0-15) 
    db 0x0          ; Base ( bits 16-23) 
    db 10011010b    ; 1 st flags , type flags 
    db 11001111b    ; 2 nd flags , Limit ( bits 16-19) 
    db 0x0          ; Base ( bits 24-31) 
gdt_data: ; the data segment descriptor 
    ; Same as code segment except for the type flags : 
    ; type flags : ( code )0 ( expand down )0 ( writable )1 ( accessed )0 -> 0010 b 
    dw 0xffff       ; Limit ( bits 0-15) 
    dw 0x0          ; Base ( bits 0-15) 
    db 0x0          ; Base ( bits 16-23) 
    db 10010010b    ; 1 st flags , type flags 
    db 11001111b    ; 2 nd flags , Limit ( bits 16-19) 
    db 0x0          ; Base ( bits 24-31) 

gdt_end:    ; The reason for putting a label at the end of the 
            ; GDT is so we can have the assembler calculate 
            ; the size of the GDT for the GDT decriptor ( below ) 
            ; GDT descriptior 
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1  ; Size of our GDT , always less one 
                                ; of the true size 
    dd gdt_start                ; Start address of our GDT 

    ; Define some handy constants for the GDT segment descriptor offsets , which 
    ; are what segment registers must contain when in protected mode. For example , 
    ; when we set DS = 0 x10 in PM , the CPU knows that we mean it to use the ; segment described at offset 0 x10 ( i.e. 16 bytes ) in our GDT , which in our 
    ; case is the DATA segment (0 x0 -> NULL ; 0 x08 -> CODE ; 0 x10 -> DATA ) 
    CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start 
    DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

Comment: And how is your function **defined** (i. e. implemented)?

Comment: @H2CO3 added definitions

Comment: you should be using `const char*`, but that is probably unrelated.

Comment: @Bartlomiej Any chance you are trying to write kernel-mode code?

Comment: @H2CO3 yes, these are called by the kernel

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Ah well then that's it! If you are using a string literal, then there's a good chance you are messing up the layout of your exectuable, and the entry point is shifted to an incorrect location.

Comment: @H2CO3 Where does C store string literals? It may be that they are saved in the wrong place - and since i'm using bochs that fills all the memory with zeros, i get an empty string

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski, read-only. The first instance of double quotes is an array initializer syntax (not a string literal) but the second is a string literal.

Comment: @JacobPollack In fact, the first snippet **is** a string literal too - it's just that most probably it's so short that the compiler doesn't actually create a string literal to initialize the array with, but it substitutes four `mov [esp + idx]` instructions instead.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Read [this](http://osdev.berlios.de/ckernel.html#tools), especially the part immediately following the code snippet.

Comment: @H2CO3, I am not quite sure I understand what you're saying by "*it's just that most probably it's so long that the compiler doesn't actually create a string literal to initialize the array with*". Can you explain that part again (differently)?

Comment: @JacobPollack Ah, sorry. I meant "so short", of course. I'm tired, whatever.

Comment: @H2CO3 I already have a small function that calls the start function, so it is not the problem of placement of the string.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Well, are you sure? Have you checked the resulting assembly and the binary in a HEX editor?

Comment: yes, right after the first sector i have a jump to my start function

Comment: What exactly is loading this code? What "kernel" are you using?

Comment: @MatsPetersson my own, i updated my question with the initialising of protected mode and setting the segment registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, after looking at a disassembly with a much bigger string.

The reason was the way I linked the kernel. These were the commands I was advised to use:

```
ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary
```

but since I had a windows gcc, and my asm and C files were in elf format, I had to use this trick:

```
ld -o kernel.out -Ttext 0x1000 $^ 
objcopy -O binary -j .text kernel.out $@
```

This copied only the text part of the object, so I was left with the binary version.
Since I only copied the **.text** part of the object, my strings that were kept in the **.rdata** sections were lost. So it was simply a matter of adding this to objcopy:

```
objcopy -O binary -j .text -j .rdata kernel.out $@
```

Answer (score -1):

When you say print(s), you are passing it as char array beacuse you have declared "s". But when you pass as print("abc"). What is the type of "abc". It's not defined. I guess this is your problem. I would also recommend you to change your char s[] to char *s. Hope this helps.

Comment: The datatype of "abc" (a literal string) is clearly defined to be a character pointer. There's nothing undefined about it. And there is NO difference between char s[], and char * s;

Comment: @amrith : char s[] and char* are not actually same. Please do go through some references. Here is an example. Take a look. Cheers!!char *s="hello", here s can point any another string at run time I mean it is not constant pointer you can assign another value at run time p = "Nishant", while s[] here s is constant pointer....it can't be reasign another string but we can assign another character value at s[index].

Comment: The difference here is that

char *s = "Hello world";
will place Hello world in the read-only parts of the memory and making s a pointer to that, making any writing operation on this memory illegal. While doing:

char s[] = "Hello world";
puts the literal string in read-only memory and copies the string to newly allocated memory on the stack. Making

s[0] = 'J';
legal.